# Is there a way to remember the position in a python iterator?

Tags: python, iterator, generator

I would like to iterate over an iterable object (let's say, a list) and leave at some point remembering the position where I left off to continue the next time an iterator for that object is called.

Something like:

```
for val in list:
   do_stuff(val)
   if some_condition:
       break

do_stuff()

for val in list:
    continue_doing_stuff(val)
```

Speed matters and the list considered is quite large. So saving the object and iterating again through the whole list until the saved element is found is not an option. Is this possible without writing an explicit iterator class for the list?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `__iter__` method is called when you enter a for loop with an object, returning an iterator. We usually don't keep a name pointing to the iterator, but if we do, we can stop the iterating, do something else, and then resume the iterating.

The best way to get the iterator object is to use the builtin `iter` function:

```
a_list = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
iter_list = iter(a_list)

for val in iter_list:
   print(val)                # do_stuff(val)
   if val == 'b':            # some_condition!
       break

print('taking a break')      # do_stuff()

for val in iter_list:
    print(val)               # continue_doing_stuff(val)
```

shows:

```
a
b
taking a break
c
d
```

`iter(obj)` just returns the result of `obj.__iter__()`, which should be an iterator implementing a `.__next__()` method.

That `__next__` method is called for each iteration, returning the object (in this case, a character.)

If you want to call the `__next__` method yourself instead of having it called by the for loop, you should use the builtin `next` function:

```
a_list = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
iter_list = iter(a_list)
print(next(iter_list))       # do_stuff(val)
print(next(iter_list))
print('taking a break')      # do_stuff()
print(next(iter_list))       # continue_doing_stuff(val)
print(next(iter_list))
```

prints:

```
a
b
taking a break
c
d
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use a generator to do this

```
def get_next(iterator):
    for item in iterator:
        yield item

my_list_iterator = get_next(my_list)

for val in my_list_iterator:
    do_stuff(val)
    if some_condition:
        break

do_stuff()

for val in my_list_iterator:
    continue_doing_stuff(val)
```

Comment: Can you expand on what benefit you see from defining a generator over using `iter`? As far as I can tell `get_next` behaves identically to `iter(my_list)`. Both approaches should work but I generally prefer using the builtins when they do everything that's needed.

Comment: @PeterDeGlopper For this *particular case*, `iter` should be fine.

Comment: Thanks, it looks like we generally agree. I mildly disagree with @yopy's comment saying "this should be the answer" (though I do not claim that this answer is wrong - it's a perfectly valid approach) given my preference for the builtin, and maybe I should have addressed my comment accordingly. Picking between them just looks like a choice between explicitly declared behavior versus built in behavior, which is very much subjective.

Comment: i took back my words, iter(iterables) can solve what he needs for this particular case. Thanks for the feedback.