# Re/Storing node position in XML ElementTree [Py3]

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

In Python3 ElementTree how can I get an XML node position stored then restored to continue traversing from there? (waiting for async user inputs in an XML tree)

Node object has an address, can I save this then restore it, like a C pointer?

```
<Element 'entry' at 0x00000000026C4D68>
```

Less efficient option I thought was to hash each node, and do matching search from the beginning.

```
# parse XML
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse('tree.xml')
root = tree.getroot()

# start traversing
for child in root:
  # after few iterations need to abort traversing, save current node
  save(child)
  break

# later on I need to restore the node where I stopped
previousNode = restore()

# continue from the restored node downwards
for child in previousNode:
  pass
```

Comment: Perhaps you could use `root.iter()`, which creates an iterator. https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.Element.iter

Comment: It would be nice if I could store the location in cookie, ie text based.

Comment: I don't know if storing the position as a text cookie is possible. But an iterator keeps track of the position automatically. https://stackoverflow.com/q/21594302/407651